# Autoclicker that moves mouse using relative coordinates

Tags: gratis, open-source, automation, mouse

I need to place objects in a map. They are a lot but distributed regularly (zig-zag).

I need an "auto-clicker" that can repeatedly:

- click
- move mouse of +5 pixels on y axis
- click
- move mouse of +3 pixels on x axis and -5 on y axis
- click
- repeat for n times

It should be Open Source, or free with a "clean" installer.

Most auto-clickers I've seen use absolute screen positions, I don't need that.

If you can suggest a more complex program for macros, that's fine (as long as the above requirements are satisfied).

I tried Auto Mouse Clicker, Move Mouse, MouseBot, AutoMouser and looked at the screenshots of some others.

Thanks.

Comment: "Most auto-clickers I've seen use absolute screen positions, I don't need that." -> can you specify the ones you tried? –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Microsoft Windows, you use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (free, open-source), which provides:

- a [MouseGetPos](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseGetPos.htm) function to retrieve the current position of the mouse cursor.
- a [MouseMove](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseMove.htm) to move the mouse cursor.
- [MouseClick](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm)

Comment: Looks nice, stuff for a programmer really. Would you be so kind as to provide a script too? You can start from position (20, 95). Thanks.